# One instance of control sharing property with another?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, custom-controls

I created my own toolbar. Inside toolbar I have collection property to display custom items:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CustomItems", typeof(List<UIElement>), typeof(DitatToolbar), new PropertyMetadata(new List<UIElement>()));

        public List<UIElement> CustomItems
        {
            get { return GetValue(CustomItemsProperty) as List<UIElement>; }
            set { this.SetValue(CustomItemsProperty, value); }
        }
```

On one of my views I declared toolbar with one custom item:

```
<my:DitatToolbar
            Status="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource ViewEditingStateToToolbarStateConverter}}"
            Mode="DataEntry">
            <my:DitatToolbar.CustomItems>
                <my:DitatToolbarButton Icon="/IDATT.Infrastructure.SL;component/Images/img_btn_calculate.png" Caption="Next&#x0d;&#x0a;Number" Index="6" Command="{Binding GetNextNumberCommand}" />
            </my:DitatToolbar.CustomItems>
        </my:DitatToolbar>
```

Basically, I wanted to place custom "Get next Number" button on my toolbar. Inside `onApplyTemplate` I call this method:

```
internal void BuildUi()
    {

    if (this.ButtonsStackPanel == null) return;

    this.defaultStatusVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    this.defaultNavigationVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    this.ButtonsStackPanel.Children.Clear();
    this.Items = new List<UIElement>();

    // Add buttons according to our work mode:
    switch (this.Mode)
    {
        case ModeType.Ok:
            this.Items.Add(this.GetNewButton(ButtonType.Ok));
            break;

        case ModeType.OkCancel:
            this.Items.Add(this.GetNewButton(ButtonType.Ok));
            this.Items.Add(this.GetNewButton(ButtonType.Cancel));
            break;

        case ModeType.Lookup:
            this.Items.Add(this.GetNewButton(ButtonType.CancelExit));
            this.Items.Add(this.GetNewButton(ButtonType.Ok));
            this.Items.Add(new DitatToolbarSeparator());
            this.Items.Add(this.GetNewButton(ButtonType.Refresh));
            break;

        case ModeType.DataEntry:
            this.defaultStatusVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            this.defaultNavigationVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            this.Items.Add(this.GetNewButton(ButtonType.CancelExit));
            this.Items.Add(this.GetNewButton(ButtonType.SaveExit));
            this.Items.Add(new DitatToolbarSeparator());
            this.Items.Add(this.GetNewButton(ButtonType.Cancel));
            this.Items.Add(this.GetNewButton(ButtonType.SaveClose));
            this.Items.Add(new DitatToolbarSeparator());
            this.Items.Add(this.GetNewButton(ButtonType.RenameId));
            this.Items.Add(this.GetNewButton(ButtonType.Delete));
            break;

        case ModeType.OptionsDataEntry:
            this.defaultStatusVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            this.Items.Add(this.GetNewButton(ButtonType.CancelExit));
            this.Items.Add(this.GetNewButton(ButtonType.SaveExit));
            this.Items.Add(new DitatToolbarSeparator());
            this.Items.Add(this.GetNewButton(ButtonType.Save));
            break;

        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException("DitatToolbar Mode have to be specified");
    }

    if (this.Mode == ModeType.DataEntry || this.Mode == ModeType.OptionsDataEntry)
    {
        if (GetBindingExpression(CanEditProperty) == null)
        {
            this.SetBinding(CanEditProperty, new Binding("CanEdit") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
        }

        if (GetBindingExpression(CanDeleteProperty) == null)
        {
            this.SetBinding(CanDeleteProperty, new Binding("CanDelete") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
        }

        if (GetBindingExpression(CanRenameProperty) == null)
        {
            this.SetBinding(CanRenameProperty, new Binding("CanRename") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
        }
    }

    // Add custom buttons:
    foreach (var customItem in this.CustomItems)
    {
        var ci = customItem as IToolbarItem;
        this.Items.Insert(ci.Index, customItem);
    }

    // Insert buttons into container:
    foreach (var element in this.Items)
    {
        this.ButtonsStackPanel.Children.Add(element);
    }

    // Navigation panel visibility
    this.ShowNavigation();

    // Status panel visibility
    this.ChangeStatus();
}
```

My problem is that for some reason ALL toolbars in my app (various views) see this custom item that I declared only on one view. This causing issues obviously. I wonder what is wrong with my code that `CustomItem` dependency property becomes STATIC to whole APP?

**ANSWER**

Dependency property had to be declared like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomItemsProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("CustomItems", typeof(List<UIElement>), typeof(DitatToolbar), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

And I added initialization of this property to constructor:

```
public DitatToolbar()
        {
            this.CustomItems = new List<UIElement>();

            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(DitatToolbar);
        }
```

Comment: If you comment out the custom item from the one view that has it, does it disappear from all the other views?

Comment: It's not like that. Right now other view get exception at run time saying that this UI element child of other container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the default value that you have given the property in the typeMetadata parameter (`new PropertyMetadata(new List<UIElement>()`) is shared across all instances - i.e they will all start off with the same empty list. Use null as the default value and instead initialise an empty list per control in the constructor.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a lot, that was it (I updated my post with answer) (I was able to upvote but for some reason it wouldn't take as answer, will try later)